# Swap program using function NOT WORKING in C

Tags: c, printf, swap

/*Numbers entered should be swapped and displayed. This simple program looks fine according to me but it's not. I have tried using printf("%d%d") it works but using default value on the stack. But it ain't working using this code.I have tried different compilers like TurboC++, CodeBlocks(GCC) . Can someone please help me with explanation? Thanks in advance*/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void swap(int,int );
int main()

{
    int x,y;
    printf("Two Numbers: ");
    scanf("%d\n%d",&x,&y);
    swap(x,y);
    printf("%d%d",x,y);//printf("%d%d"); makes the program work but not genuinely 
    return 0;
    getch();
}
void swap(int x,int y)
{
    int temp;
    temp=y;
    y=x;
    x=temp;
}
```

Comment: I'm not a C/C++ person, but I can see that your `swap` method is only swapping the values of the variables _local_ to that function.  In the caller `main()` function, nothing will change.  See the duplicate link for more information.

Comment: In order to write a swap function in C you need to know about *pointers* and *pass-by-reference*. Look at the call to `scanf` in your program. Do you know what those squiggly symbols are doing there?

Comment: I got your point @TimBiegeleisen  
Thanks a lot for helping me!! :)

Comment: I got your point @n.m. Thanks a lot for helping me!! :)

Answer (score 3):

You are only changing the values of x, y which exists only inside the method swap. The swap method is creating objects x,y having a new memory mapping for the swap method only. They do not exist outside the method swap. You need to pass the memory address reference of the values so that the operation is done on the memory address of the original values. Swap needs to accept the memory reference of the values and store them in pointers which will perform operations to the original values' memory location.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void swap(int*,int* );
int main()

{
    int x,y;
    printf("Two Numbers: ");
    scanf("%d\n%d",&x,&y);
    swap(&x,&y);
    printf("%d%d",x,y);//printf("%d%d"); makes the program work but not genuinely 
    return 0;

}
void swap(int *x,int *y)
{
    int temp;
    temp=*y;
    *y=*x;
    *x=temp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You've been a great help, I got it now! :)